# Turning off my pet's idle sound?

Tags: torchlight-2

Is there a way to turn off pet idle sounds in Torchlight 2? I'd rather not hear random growls when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out. I read [this](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=44825#p406738) guide, however I can't seem to find my game data. I installed the game with using Steam, so I might be out of luck. One possibility is to pause the game, but that doesn't silence the pet while I'm sorting through my inventory.

Comment: Lately, I've been choosing my pet solely on the basis of which ones have the least annoying idle sound, so I'd love to see an option to disable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

- Replacing the sound files with a blank one, which in my opinion should not be used because multiple creatures could use the same sound file.
- Editing the sound file to reduce the volume which some program such as audacity then save and replace it.

But be careful, because any errors while doing this can cause your game to crash.

Your steam games install to 
C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\YourSteam\Torchlight2

Inside you should be able to find everything you need to follow that website and the tips i got from the website.